# wix 3.0 unexpected child element 'Website'

Tags: windows, installation, wix

I am trying to create a website installer and am using wix.  i am using this tutorial 
http://www.dalun.com/wix/01.05.2007.htm

i had to change my script to use

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
```

because it was complaining about

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi'>
```

so my script looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
   <Product Id='6197b262-b2d8-464c-9d0b-6cade171b46f' Name='WixWebSiteExample' Language='1033' Version='0.0.0.0' Manufacturer='Corporation'>
      <Package Id='439d5627-cc07-4a41-9f50-b201ae3f8202' Description='Creating a web site with WiX' Comments='Creating a web site with WiX' InstallerVersion='200' Compressed='yes' />

      <Media Id='1' Cabinet='product.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />

      <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
         <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
            <Directory Id='ApplicationFolder' Name='AppDir'>
               <Component Id='WebSiteComponent' Guid='6b27e78e-bcbc-462a-bd7a-50cf991c7d39' DiskId='1'>
                  <File Id='WixExampleFile' Name='simple.txt' src='bin\simple.txt' />
                  <WebSite Id='DefaultWebSite' Description='My First Web Site Created With WiX' Directory='ApplicationFolder'>
                    <WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
                  </WebSite>
               </Component>
               <Component Id="WebVirtualDirComponent" Guid="8d7c59c0-b84d-40d9-b3a5-0c73b6487ae4">
                   <WebVirtualDir Id="VDir" Alias="Test" Directory="ApplicationFolder" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
                       <WebApplication Id="TestWebApplication" Name="Test" />
                   </WebVirtualDir>
               </Component>
            </Directory>
         </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Feature Id='TestProductFeature' Title='Wix File Product Feature' Level='1'>
         <ComponentRef Id='WebSiteComponent' />
         <ComponentRef Id='WebVirtualDirComponent' />         
      </Feature>
   </Product>
</Wix>
```

I am getting this error

C:\Downloads\wix3.0.5419.0-binaries\firstWebsite\firstwebsite.wxs(13) : error CN
DL0005 : The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'WebSite'.
C:\Downloads\wix3.0.5419.0-binaries\firstWebsite\firstwebsite.wxs(18) : error CN
DL0005 : The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'WebVirtualD
ir'.

is Website tag not supported in wix 3.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In wix 3.0, the website element is in a [different namespace](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_index.htm). Declare the namespace by changing the wix element from

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
```

to

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' 
   xmlns:iis='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension'>
```

and then refer to the `<WebSite>` element as `<iis:WebSite>`. Add the same prefix to the other web-related elements.

Furthermore, you need to run `candle.exe` and `light.exe` with this option: `-ext WixIIsExtension`.

Answer (score 2):

When upgrading from WiX v2 source code to WiX v3 source code, try using the WiX v3 tool WixCop.exe. It'll fix these sorts of things for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add reference to WixIIsExtension.dll to the Wix Setup Project. Dll can be found in install bin directory. e.g. C:\Program Files\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\WixIIsExtension.dll